# WhatsApp link with phone number doesn't open WhatsApp's web app

Tags: whatsapp

What I am trying to do is to open a link in the WhatsApp web app, it works in Chrome but in FF and IE, doesn't.

**Firefox:**

- this is the link `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=[phone number]`, when the link loads it beign redirected to this link `whatsapp://send/?phone= [phone number]`

[image]

**Internet Explorer 11**

- when I try to open the link in IE11 I am asked to allow an app to be opened

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this link from? And what do you believe you will get if you successfully follow the link?

Comment: I got the link from here https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030 and what it do at least in Chrome is to open the web app and start a chat with the phone you passed as parameter in the URL. Actualy I found a solution to the problem as I changed `api` part in the URL with `web` and it works only in IE there is a massage for browser incompatibility and in IE Edge there is a message for upgrading you version to 13+

Comment: [Workaround](http://smartmanoj.blogspot.com/2018/07/click-2-chat-for-whatsapp-web-firefox.html)

Answer (score 25):

The solution here is to replace the `api` part with `web`, so your URL will look like this `https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone= [phone number]`

Comment: Yes, but if you change api for web, then it won't work in mobiles.

Comment: Awesome... Thank you very much!

Comment: also if it is onetime thing, you can use this tool https://whatsapp.akarsh.me/

Comment: Thanks for the "trick", ahahaha. My hero...

Comment: thanks. solved!

Comment: Whatsapp recently released an update on Jan 21, which breaks this. Now they are not allowing to send a message without saving number as contact.