# Open telegram web site by a mobile phone number in link

Tags: telegram

Is there any way to open telegram application from a website being in a mobile? I know if you use telegram:// you can open telegram app, but how can I open telegram and create a new conversation with a given number? i know it is possible by whatsapp like [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106145/whatsapp-link-with-phone-number-doesnt-open-whatsapps-web-app):

> this is the link https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=359883378007,
>   when the link loads it beign redirected to this link
>   whatsapp://send/?phone=359883378007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is if you have a username. Provided you have one your profile address is **t.me/username**

Phone number in url is not supported.